# How can I migrate Plesk to WHM efficiently

Tags: cpanel, migration, plesk, whm

I need to transfer my account and all its details from Plesk to a newly created WHM account. So far, I have not been able to find an easy way to do this.

I have multiple sites, with large databases and many emails.

Is there an efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

- In WHM (v11.46) there is an option under `Home » Transfers » Transfer Tool`
  (in older version it was `Copy an Account From Another Account`).

  Here, under `Advanced` option, choose `Remote Server Type:` `Parallel Plesk` and fill up the other required data and submit it.
- cPanel Migration Team also provide Free Migration Service. Check out [cPanel.net :: Migration Services](http://cpanel.net/cpanel-whm/migrate-cpanel/) for more details,

**Suggestions:**

1. Make sure you have enough disk space available on Plesk server for backup creation, or split the migration by selecting less accounts at a time.
2. Schedule the migration during low traffic period as this process can cause load on the server, or due to low disk space the websites might face unusual behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry i was away. I will look into this and will surely inform you how things goes.

Comment: I am getting an getting an error while trying this that can be seen [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KvItm.png).

Comment: no worries. the error is due to either the password is incorrect or SSH is not permitted on the selected user account.